# Custom master page needs to be uploaded under which category

Tags: 2013, custom, file-upload

I am new to SharePoint and I have doubt regarding this because most of them have given different answer.Which is correct among this?

> look and feel >> master page
>   site collection feature >> SharePoint
>   publishing infrastructure
>   site feature >> SharePoint server publishing
>   Web designer gallery >> master page and page layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid confusing, Regardless you are using Team Site or Publishing Site , you should be aware of the recommended method to work with SharePoint branding 2013 and upload your custom master page is to use `Design Manager`.

- Site Settings > Look and feel > Design manager.

**Design Manager consists of the following sections**

1. Welcome
2. Manage Device Channels
3. Upload Design Files
4. Edit Master Pages
5. Edit Display Templates
6. Edit Page Layouts
7. Publish and Apply Design
8. Create Design Package

[image]

**To upload your Custom Master Page , navigate to**

- Web Designer Gallery > Master Page. or directly via    `http://rootsite/_catalogs/masterpage/`

**Check also a brief description to the sections that have been mentioned in your question.**

- look and feel > master page.

  - this only available in publishing site but you can use the same functionality from Design manager via "`Publish and Apply Design`" in Design Manager.
- site collection feature > SharePoint publishing infrastructure

  - Provides centralized libraries, content types, master pages and page layouts and enables page scheduling and other publishing functionality for a site collection.
- site feature >> SharePoint server publishing.

  - Create a Web page library as well as supporting libraries to create and publish pages based on page layouts. it's also let the current collaboration team site to work as publishing site, but in this case, you can't save your site as template.
- Web designer gallery > master page and page layout.

  - Is considered as a  document library to contains the default and custom Master / page layout as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

Below steps will help you to upload and use that master page in a right way.

**Steps:**

- Go to the **Site Settings** >> **Site collection feature** >> activate  **SharePoint publishing infrastructure** feature.
- Go to the **Site Settings** >> **Site feature** >> activate **SharePoint server publishing** feature.
- Go to the **Site Settings** >> Under Web Designer Galleries click
  **Master Pages and Page layouts**
- From **Files** ribbon tab, Click **Upload Document** and upload the master page.
- Select the **ASP NET Master page** as content type and fill the details and check the **Compatible UI Version(s)**.
- Click **Save** button.
- Go to your uploaded master page from that and **publish** it as **major** version.
- Now it is available for use. Go to **Site Settings** >> under look and feel click **Master page**.
- You can see your uploaded master page in the dropdown. Now you can select it to set as new master page.